# Multiple markers are not properly showing in google map php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my laravel project am trying to show locations of my clinics in google maps (Taking lattitude and longitude values from php database). Follwoing is my code in controller.

```
public function showClinicLocations($id)
{
    $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
    $locations = Location::where('clinicID', $id)->get();
    return view('clinic.locations')->with(['locations' =>  $locations  ,'clinic'=>$clinic]);
}
```

In view page am properly getting `locations` .When i consoled the `locations.length` am getting the result as `12` , its correct and also am getting complete locations name.

But when i tried to show it in marker only 11 locations are showing in google map marker. Following is the code in google map marker.

```
<script>

// var services =<?php echo json_encode($services);?>;
// console.log(services);

function initMap() {
    var locations = <?php echo $locations ?>;
    console.log(locations.length);

    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) { 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
                                        {zoom: 8,
                                        center: {
                                            lat: parseFloat(locations[j]['locationLat']), 
                                            lng:parseFloat(locations[j]['locationLong'])
                                            }
                                        }
                                        );
        setMarkers(map);
    }
}

function setMarkers(map) {
    var locations = <?php echo $locations ?>;
    //var services = <?php echo $services ?>;

    //console.log(services);

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {lat: parseFloat(locations[i]['locationLat']), lng:parseFloat(locations[i]['locationLong'])},
                map: map,
                title: locations[i]['locationName']
                });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        var content = locations[i]['locationName']; 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', 
                        (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                            return function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(content);
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                            };
                        })(marker, content,infowindow));  

    }
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

What is the problem with the code of google maps to show markers

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Try to change `j < locations.length` to `j =< locations.length` on first `for`

Comment: why are you creating new maps in a loop? If you say there are 12 results expected that would mean 12 maps all being created (probably not really as they all use the same container )

Answer (score 0):

You wanna generate the map only once and maybe also fit the map to the bounds of all displayed markers:

```
var locations = JSON.parse("<?php echo $locations ?>");

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: parseFloat(locations[0]["locationLat"]),
      lng: parseFloat(locations[0]["locationLong"])
    }
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

function setMarkers(_map) {
  var boundsToFit = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i <= locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: _map,
      position: {
        lat: parseFloat(locations[i]["locationLat"]),
        lng: parseFloat(locations[i]["locationLong"])
      },
      map: _map,
      title: locations[i]["locationName"]
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var content = locations[i]["locationName"];

    google.maps.event.addListener(
      marker,
      "click",
      (function (marker, content, infowindow) {
        return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          infowindow.open(_map, marker);
        };
      })(marker, content, infowindow)
    );

    boundsToFit.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }

  _map.fitBounds(boundsToFit);
}
```